# VBA Open Workbook based on Value Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm Having trouble with my code that opens a workbook based on the value in column C and opens another workbook based on column B. The code then is supposed to paste workbook B into workbook C but the code seems to stop after opening the workbook in column C and doesn't progress to column B.

Can someone help with my loops?

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()

  'Open the summary  tracking and the assoicated weekly report on a loop

Dim WbSummary As String
Dim WbWeekly As String


r = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Workbooks("Resales Summary Report").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2)) And IsEmpty(Workbooks("Resales Summary Report").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3))


WbSummary = Workbooks("Resales Summary Report").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 3)
WbWeekly = Workbooks("Resales Summary Report").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 2)


Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Bjellis\Documents\Fast Track\Summary Reports\" & WbSummary & ""

Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Bjellis\Documents\Fast Track\Weekly Files\" & WbWeekly & ""


'Copy and Paste
 
Workbooks(WbWeekly).Sheets("Sheet").Range("A8:R48").Copy
 
Workbooks(WbSummary).Sheets("Weekly Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
  

'Close Weekly Update Workbook
Workbooks(WbWeekly).Close SaveChanges:=False

  
'Copy a range from sheet 1 of Summary
Sheets("2020 FT Tracking").Range("B23:B29").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Weekly Data").Range("T3")

Application.CutCopyMode = False

'Formulas to add cells
Sheets("Weekly Data").Activate
    Range("U3").Formula = "=E2+E9"
    Range("U4").Formula = "=Sum(F2+G2+I2+F26+G26+I26)"
    Range("U5").Formula = "=F2+F24"
    Range("U6").Formula = "=F5+G5+I5+F27+G27+I27"
    Range("U7").Formula = "=F2+F24"
    Range("U8").Formula = "=E15+E37"
    
'Close Summary Woorkbook and Loop
Workbooks(WbSummary).Close SaveChanges:=True

r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to hitch the cart before the horse. Leave the looping to last. First program one cycle correctly. Your problem is in the absence of objects. Declare `WbSummary As Workbook` and set the object. Not clear where your code is. Is it in WbSummary? Not clear why WbSummary should be opened many times or how it can be opened if it's already opened (to read from columns B & C). Not clear what's open at the beginning. Consider using FileOpen dialog box to specify a file to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign your sheets and books to object variables, and the code will be a lot more readable:

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()

  ' Open the summary  tracking and the assoicated weekly report on a loop

  Dim WbSummary As String
  Dim WbWeekly As String

  Dim SummaryBook As Workbook
  Dim WeeklyBook As Workbook

  Dim ReportSheet As Worksheet

  Set ReportSheet = Workbooks("Resales Summary Report").Sheets("Sheet1")

  r = 2
  Do Until IsEmpty(ReportSheet.Cells(r, 2)) And IsEmpty(ReportSheet.Cells(r, 3))

    WbSummary = ReportSheet.Cells(r, 3)
    WbWeekly = ReportSheet.Cells(r, 2)

    Set SummaryBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Bjellis\Documents\Fast Track\Summary Reports\" & WbSummary)
    Set WeeklyBook = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Bjellis\Documents\Fast Track\Weekly Files\" & WbWeekly)

    ' Copy and Paste
    WeeklyBook.Sheets("Sheet").Range("A8:R48").Copy
    SummaryBook.Sheets("Weekly Data").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
      
    ' Close Weekly Update Workbook
    WeeklyBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 
    ' Copy a range from sheet 1 of Summary
    Sheets("2020 FT Tracking").Range("B23:B29").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Weekly Data").Range("T3")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Formulas to add cells
    With SummaryBook.Sheets("Weekly Data")
        .Range("U3").Formula = "=E2+E9"
        .Range("U4").Formula = "=Sum(F2+G2+I2+F26+G26+I26)"
        .Range("U5").Formula = "=F2+F24"
        .Range("U6").Formula = "=F5+G5+I5+F27+G27+I27"
        .Range("U7").Formula = "=F2+F24"
        .Range("U8").Formula = "=E15+E37"
    End With

    ' Close Summary Woorkbook and Loop
    SummaryBook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    r = r + 1

    Set SummaryBook = Nothing
    Set WeeklyBook = Nothing

  Loop

  Set ReportSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

There are various other things I could tweak in your code, but I'd rather that you can clearly see what I've changed.

Comment: This is great thank you very much!! I really appreciate it

Comment: My pleasure, @B2B92 :) Do feel free to Accept the Answer :)

Comment: Now the formulas are not working. I can run through the ranges with no problem but the formulas are not being posted to the active sheet. Any idea why that might be? Many thanks

Comment: @ Rich Harding Thanks for the help, now I'm having issues getting the formulas to work on the active sheet. Any Ideas?

Comment: @B2B92 I suggest you again use object references. The code above is still relying on the sheet being activated, which is not best practice (i.e. don't activate a sheet and then assume that's the one you're changing; hold a reference to it and do it direclty. I'll amend the relevant section for you above.